# Get html elements, put them into array, and find matches

Tags: javascript

I have an attribute called 'data-industry in a bunch of HTML elements. The else if statement is where I'm having a problem.

```
<div class="b-filter-item" data-industry="Cloud Collaboration,Enterprise Application,Infrastructure as a Service,">
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to loop through all these divs while at the same time loop(?) through these data-industries and if any one of them (split by a comma) matches a dropdown I have them it will add/remove classes

```
 var items = document.getElementsByClassName('b-filter-item');

   for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var attr =  items[i].getAttribute('data-industry').split(',');
 
        if (nothing selected) {
          // this conditional works fine 

        } else if (if one attr item in array matches a dropdown item then do this){
           // not working
    
        } else {
          // works fine

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am i missing something or is this all you need?

```
    if (nothing selected) {
      // this conditional works fine 

    } else if (attr.find(a => a === "thing in dropdown")){
       // not working

    } else {
      // works fine

    }
```

Comment: I think it put me on a good path. Thanks! I'll bug you after QA if something else is wrong with this check

Answer (score 1):

Use Array#includes() and you can combine two of the conditions together. I've also used the `dataset` property simply because it's less to write then `getAttribute('data-something')`

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.b-filter-item');

document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const {value} = this;
  items.forEach(el => {
    const filters = el.dataset.industry.split(',')
    if (value && filters.includes(value)) {
      el.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.b-filter-item {
  display: none
}

.b-filter-item.active {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value=""> None </option>
  <option value="A"> A - 1 Match </option>
  <option value="C"> C - 2 Matches </option>
  <option value="F"> F - 1 Match </option>
</select>


<div class="b-filter-item" data-industry="A,B,C">
  A,B,C
</div>
<div class="b-filter-item" data-industry="C,D,E">
  C,D,E
</div>
<div class="b-filter-item" data-industry="F,G,H">
  F,G,H
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works really well, because you get the element itself for each loop. You can use `querySelectorAll` (see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_queryselectorall.asp) notation here). ex:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.b-filter-item').forEach(function(el){el.innerHTML='Welcome!'})
```

Comment: Mind giving me an example for my situation?